# thread safe call to multiple controls vb net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, .net-4.0, user-controls

I am just starting to get my head round threading with .net 4.0
It seems the best way to do this is with tasks. My problem is one of the tasks involves making multiple controls visible and also re-positioning them and I cant find anything for safe thread calls for multiple controls.

Here is the call for the tasks:

```
Parallel.Invoke(Sub()
                  HWSWChangeLayout()
                End Sub,
                Sub()
                  ValidsetUpdate1()
                End Sub)
```

And here is one of the tasks:

```
Private Sub HWSWChangeLayout()

    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() HWSWChangeLayout())
    Else
        HWSWChangeLayout()
    End If

    If strStatus = "WORK IN PROGRESS" strRole.Contains("$ORIGINATOR") Then
        'make relevant attributes visible
        Me.panCRBDate.Visible = True
        panCoordinator.Visible = True
        panSW.Visible = True
        panSW.Location = New Point(5, 189)
        panSW.Size = New Point(1216, 541)
        ET_ENG_DETS.Visible = True
        ET_FCP_DETS.Visible = True

        ET_FCP_DETS.Enabled = False
        ET_CFDU_ENG.Visible = True
        ET_CFDU_ENG.Enabled = False
        ET_PKG_DETS.Visible = True

        ET_DEP_DETS.Visible = True
        ET_DEP_DETS.Location = New Point(5, 736)
        DEP_ACT_DATE.Visible = False
        dtp_DEP_ACT_DATE.Visible = False
        lbl_DEP_ACT_DATE.Visible = False

        ET_COMMENTS.Location = New Point(5, 971)
        History.Visible = True
        Me.History.Location = New Point(5, 1206)
        Me.panAttachments.Location = New Point(5, 1441)
    End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke the control changes from the GUI-Thread. You do this with the `Me.Invoke` (aka, advise the form to do your stuff) statement like:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Public Class Form1
Private Sub DoThreadedStuff()
    'Your parallel work goes here

    'Then you want to update your main form
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() HWSWChangeLayout())
        Me.Invoke(Sub() ValidsetUpdate1())
    Else
        HWSWChangeLayout()
        ValidsetUpdate1()
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub HWSWChangeLayout()
    'Form update stuff
End Sub
Private Sub ValidsetUpdate1()
    'More Form update stuff
End Sub

Private Sub btnStartTask_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartTask.Click
    'Start the task in another thread
    Dim newTask As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() DoThreadedStuff())
End Sub
End Class
```

So you start your task (in this example) through a button click. The parallel code is in the `DoThreadedStuff` sub. From this sub you now want to update your main form as I understood you. So you Invoke the Update subs via the main form. In this way the HWSWChangeLayout and the ValidsetUpdate1 run in the GUI thread and not in your additional thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer just one question, where do I place this IF statement?

Comment: This code would go in your task (or generally the code that is running in another thread) at the place where you want to update the controls.

Comment: I added the invoke IF within the code (see above) but now the code just hangs I am obviously doing something wrong

Comment: Eh no, that's not how I meant it. It obviously hangs because the function calls itself (infinite loop). I'll edit my post in a minute to show you how to do it.